# Problems with Angular Dynamic Reactive Form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic reactive form. The user has the ability to choose between either a text (type = 1) input or img (type = 2) input. According to his choice, the right input is being added. - He can add as much input field as he wants.

I've never really used reactive forms before, hence this question.

The code below adds a control according to what module the user has chosen, but **for instance adding a textarea only displays a textarea with `[object Object]` inside - clicking makes it disappear.**

Additionally I haven't figured out yet how to submit the form's input. Logging `form` on submit **returns the form, but without the textarea's input.**

That's what I have so far:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div *ngFor="let module of form.get('modules').controls; let i = index" class="position-relative" [style.padding-bottom.rem]="paddingValue" (mouseover)="showPaddingInput = true" formArrayName="modules">

      <div class="padding-input position-absolute d-flex justify-content-center" *ngIf="showPaddingInput === true" [style.height.rem]="paddingValue">
        <input type="text" class="align-self-center text-center padding-input-field" [value]="paddingValue" (input)="changePadding(padding.value)" #padding>
      </div>

      <div class="text" *ngIf="module.value.type === 1">
        <textarea class="flow-text" placeholder="Some Text..." rows="3" [formControlName]="i"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="img-container" *ngIf="module.value.type === 2">
        <div class="custom-file align-self-center">
          <input type="file" id="i" class="custom-file-input" [formControlName]="i" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="i"></label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>

</form>
```

```
export class CreateCaseCmsComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private caseService: CasesService) { }

  addModule(type) {
    if (type === 1) {
      const control = new FormControl({type: 1}, Validators.required);
      (this.form.get('modules') as FormArray).push(control);
    } else if (type === 2) {
      const control = new FormControl({type: 2}, Validators.required);
      (this.form.get('modules') as FormArray).push(control);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      modules: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first argument to a form control is it's value, so you're setting the initial value as an object and that's why it's showing [object Object] in the text box... that's what you get if you call .toString() on an object, you need to instantiate them like this:

```
const control = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

or something like that... this affects how you're building your template, so you probably need something more like:

```
const group = new FormGroup({
   type: new FormControl(1),
   value: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});
```

and add that group to your array and access it like:

```
  <div class="text" *ngIf="module.get('type').value === 1" [formGroupName]="i">
    <textarea class="flow-text" placeholder="Some Text..." rows="3" formControlName="value"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me. One more thing though - how do I get this exact array's data on submit?